# Set a click event on a prototype function

Tags: javascript

I set a method on an objects prototype.  I want the function to run when a button is clicked (the button is in the dom, with an id of 'step')

```
GoL.prototype.step = function () { // ...
```

I would to get GoL.prototype.step to execute the code below whenever the button is clicked.  How would I go about setting a click event on the prototype method 'step'?

Comment: You bind the event handler like any other event handler and inside of it, you would do `instanceOfGoL.step()`, where `instanceOfGoL` is the instance of `GoL` you want to run the method on. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: *Please* store a reference to the element, it will probably halve your code: `var el = document.getElementById(getCellId(ix,iy))`. And it will make the function much more efficient. You could probably also have a separate function to count the number of adjacent "live" elements.

Comment: The full function listing is not really relevant for the question you're asking. Consider just leaving the function header (`GoL.prototype.step = function () {`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create an instance of `GoL` and then bind a `click` handler to the "step" button.

```
var instanceOfGoL = new GoL(); // only you know how to correctly initialize this
var button = document.getElementById('step');
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    instanceOfGoL.step();
});
```

You need to wrap it in a function and use [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) because the event handler strips the member function of scope, and you need to fill it back in.

There was no need to provide the code for the proto function, your question isn't really related to it.

Comment: `instanceOfGoL.step.call(instanceOfGoL);` is equivalent to `instanceOfGoL.step();` (which is simpler). There is no need to use `.call`.

Comment: @FelixKling No, since it's in an event handler, the function's `this` is set to the DOM element. We want it to be set to the instance, as the function expects.

Comment: Using `.call` is not needed, instanceOfGoL is already the invoking of object. It's like doing `window.call.setTimeout(window,...`

Comment: You are right, *inside the event handler* , this refers to the DOM elements. But you are not using this inside the handler! And when you are calling an object method like obj.func() then inside func, this will refer to obj. Just try it for yourself if you don't believe me :) you can read up about this in the MDN documentation.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for all the help so far, I really appreciate all of this.  I understand what is happening with this snippet of code but I'm struggling to figure out where to put this in my code.  Is it normal to set an area of your js file for multiple event listeners(I have a few other buttons I haven't finished the functions for yet but I imagine I can place all of them with the instanceOfGol var we create here).

Comment: @Codey Put it in your DOMReady or onload handler. Or anywhere in your markup after the button element.

Comment: @FelixKling Ooops! Sorry sorry. You're right, I just wasn't thinking straight.

Answer (score 0):

A good point was raised by Codey in the comments.

> I'm struggling to figure out where to put this in my code.

The best place would be in a file/object that defines the DOM interaction and is responsible for getting/setting DOM values and react to user input.

This because you know where to find DOM dependent code when you plan to change the UI or decide to change/use a library like jQuery and need to re factor this code.

You can only get elements and add/set event handlers to it when the element is there so trying to set event handlers in code that is immediately run and added in the `<head>` section would not work.

I usually add code that needs dom elements to be there directly above the closing `</body>` tag. You can add it earlier like directly after the element that you're interested in.

A DOM dependent object could look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test page for DomDependent</title>
</head>
 <body>
     <input type="button" data-click="button was clicked" value="click me">
     <input type="button" value="does not log, no data-click">
     <select data-change="select value changed">
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
     </select>
  <script>
    //all code interacting with DOM should go here
    var DomDependent = {
      init:function(){
        document.body.onclick=DomDependent.click;
        //change may not bubble/propagate in <IE9
        document.body.onchange=DomDependent.change;
        //dynamically add element(s), because the handler is on
        //  document this element will still trigger the event
        var txt=document.createElement("input");
        txt.type="text";
        //set data-change attribute because we want something 
        //  done when it changes
        txt.setAttribute("data-change","txt changed");
        document.body.appendChild(txt);
      },
      getEvent:function(e){
        //for IE
        return e || window.event;
      },
      click:function(e){
        e = DomDependent.getEvent(e);
        var todo=e.target.getAttribute("data-click");
        //only do something if data-click is defined (see html)
        if(todo){
          //You could trigger an event in a mediator object here
          //  in this example we use data-click to define what 
          //  needs to be done
          console.log("something needs to be done, ",
            todo,"the element:",e.target);
        }
      },
      change:function(e){
        e = DomDependent.getEvent(e);
        var todo=e.target.getAttribute("data-change");
        //only do something if data-change is defined (see html)
        if(todo){
          console.log("something needs to be done, ",
            todo,"the element:",e.target);
        }
      }
    };
    DomDependent.init();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While you certainly put a lot of effort into the answer, it doesn't really seem to address the OP's problem. The question wasn't about 'this'.

Comment: @FelixKling yes, looking at the code again it is unclear what is asked. Now the OP would like the id of step but can't find any object that has a member called id. I guessed the OP got in trouble with using `this` as sometimes the OP would like it to be the element and sometimes he would like it to be the GoL instance (assuming that's the object that has the `id` member)